# count a text that appears between two other texts in a column in python

Tags: python, excel

[The sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma2UP.jpg)

Hello, I am totally new to python and need help in this particular problem.

My excel sheet contains two column Slides and Slide Number.

I would like to take the first column and find the first two Centre_Target, and see if there is Correction_Image between them, if correction image is there between them then count the occurrences of **Image 1** between the Centre_Target and Correction_Image. And continue this count of image 1 in similar pattern till the last Centre_Target.

In the .jpg image, I have attached

Answer: The no. of image 1 count here according to the condition is: 1

I need help in coding this in python
Much Thanks!

Comment: *"need help"* != *"need someone to code it for me"* Please show your efforts thus far, and describe where you have a problem.

Comment: Sorry! Not a freelance website to do the work for you.